# Probability of duplicate selections across sets (Combinatorics)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you have 100 distinct video games and you have 50 distinct friends, each of which you must offer 3 video games from your collection of 100. Each of your 50 friends must select one of the three video games you present them with. 
Assumptions: 
(1) All offers must be made simultaneously. 
(2) You may offer the same game to multiple friends. 
(3) Each set of 3 video games offered for selection as well as each video game ultimately chosen by a friend has an equal probability of selection.

The question is how many distinct games will be chosen more than once?

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this problem? Is there any theorem or formula that would be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "set of 3" seems to be a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring): it makes no difference to the ultimate distribution (each person chooses a game with equal probability).  This can be shown as below (but should be apparent from the problem description):
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Pr}[i \text{ chosen}] &= \mathrm{Pr}[i \text{ in set of three}\ \cap\ i \text{ chosen of the three}] \\
 &= \mathrm{Pr}[i \text{ chosen of the three}\ |\ i \text{ in set of three}] \times \mathrm{Pr}[i \text{ in set of three}] \\
 &= \tfrac{1}{3} \times \frac{\binom{99}{2}}{\binom{100}{3}} \\
 &= \tfrac{1}{3} \times \frac{\tfrac{1}{2} \times 99 \times 98}{\tfrac{1}{6} \times 100 \times 99 \times 98} \\
 &= \tfrac{1}{100}.
\end{align*}

So, we can assume each of the $50$ people choose games uniformly at random.

> How many distinct games will be chosen more than once?

If this means "what is the expected number of games that are chosen more than once?" then we can use [linearity of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity):

\begin{align*}
 & \mathrm{Exp}[\text{games chosen more than once}] \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^{100} \mathrm{Pr}[\text{game } i \text{ chosen more than once}] \\
 &= 100 \times \mathrm{Pr}[\text{game } 1 \text{ chosen more than once}] \\
 &= 100 \times \sum_{i=2}^{50} \mathrm{Pr}[\text{game } 1 \text{ chosen } i \text{ times} ] \\
 &= 100 \times \left(1-\mathrm{Pr}[\text{game } 1 \text{ not chosen}]-\mathrm{Pr}[\text{game } 1 \text{ chosen } 1 \text{ time}] \right). \\
\end{align*}
What remains is to find $\mathrm{Pr}[\text{game } 1 \text{ chosen } i \text{ times}]$ which is [binomially distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with probability $p=\tfrac{1}{100}$ and number of trials $n=50$.